# SQL Query within nested for loops in C# windows forms application taking too long to execute

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I am working on a Windows Forms C# Application in which I have a method which has nested `for` loop that is used to retrieve data from an SQL Table  with different parameters (`trademonth` and `paymentmonth` that are passed from the row and column headers of a `DataGridView`  and the function also stores the data retrieved from the table into the `DataGridView`.

As I have around 36 rows (`trademonths`) and 31 columns (`paymentmonths`), So the `for` loops run the same query with different parameters for 36*31 times.

I have the following lines of code in the function

```
public void CalculatePoolPayments(DataGridView datagridpool, string poolpayments, string poolpaymentadjustments)
        {
            sqlcon = GetConnectionString();
            try
            {
                sqlcon.Open();


                for (int i = 0; i < datagridpool.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    int trademonth = Convert.ToInt32(datagridpool.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value);


                    for (int j = 0; j < datagridpool.ColumnCount; j++)
                    {
                        int paymentmonth = Convert.ToInt32(datagridpool.Columns[j].HeaderCell.Value);

                        SqlCommand poolpaymentscmd = new SqlCommand(poolpayments, sqlcon);

                        poolpaymentscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trademonth", trademonth);
                        poolpaymentscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentmonth", paymentmonth);
                        DataTable dtExpectedAmount = new DataTable();
                        SqlDataAdapter daExpectedAmount = new SqlDataAdapter();

                        daExpectedAmount.SelectCommand = poolpaymentscmd;
                        daExpectedAmount.Fill(dtExpectedAmount);

                        SqlCommand poolpaymentsadjustmentcmd = new SqlCommand(poolpaymentadjustments, sqlcon);
                        poolpaymentsadjustmentcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trademonth", trademonth);
                        poolpaymentsadjustmentcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentmonth", paymentmonth);

                        DataTable dtAdjustment = new DataTable();
                        SqlDataAdapter daAdjustment = new SqlDataAdapter();

                        daAdjustment.SelectCommand = poolpaymentsadjustmentcmd;
                        daAdjustment.Fill(dtAdjustment);



                        if (dtExpectedAmount.Rows[0][0].ToString() != "")
                        {
                            datagridpool.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = dtExpectedAmount.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                            if (dtAdjustment.Rows[0][0].ToString() != "")
                            {
                                datagridpool.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(dtAdjustment.Rows[0][0].ToString()) + Convert.ToDouble(dtExpectedAmount.Rows[0][0].ToString())).ToString();
                            }

                        }
                        else
                            datagridpool.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = 0;

                        if (dtExpectedAmount.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "" && dtAdjustment.Rows[0][0].ToString() != "")
                        {
                            datagridpool.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = dtAdjustment.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                        }

                        // MessageBox.Show(datagridpool.Rows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString());
                    }
                }

                sqlcon.Close();
            }

            catch (SqlException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
                sqlcon.Close();

            }


        }
```

**SQL Queries**

```
string poolpayments = @"SELECT        SUM(a.ExpectedAmt) AS Payment
                                    FROM            PaymentReceivable AS a WITH (nolock) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                    Confirmations AS b WITH (nolock) ON a.ConfirmationID = b.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                    Users AS c WITH (nolock) ON b.BuyBroker = c.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                    Users AS d WITH (nolock) ON b.SellBroker = d.ID
                                    WHERE        (a.TradeDateMonth = @trademonth) AND (a.Payment = 'True') AND (a.PaymentDateMonth = @paymentmonth)  AND (Adjustment=0 OR Adjustment IS NULL)";

string poolpaymentadjustments = @"SELECT        SUM(a.Adjustment) AS Payment
                                        FROM            PaymentReceivable AS a WITH (nolock) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                        Confirmations AS b WITH (nolock) ON a.ConfirmationID = b.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                        Users AS c WITH (nolock) ON b.BuyBroker = c.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                        Users AS d WITH (nolock) ON b.SellBroker = d.ID
                                        WHERE        (a.TradeDateMonth = @trademonth) AND (a.Payment = 'True') AND (a.PaymentDateMonth = @paymentmonth) AND (Adjustment!=0 OR Adjustment IS NOT NULL)";
```

As you can see from the above code I am running two different queries `poolpaymentscmd` and `poolpaymentsadjustmentcmd` with parameters `trademonth` and `paymentmonth`.

The function is taking around 90 seconds to execute and I am using the same function two times as required by my application. So, the single function is taking up to 180 seconds which I feel is too high for the application.

Is there any better way I can reduce the execution time

Comment: Execute the SQL as one batch command (either a view or stored proc), instead of looping, and return the entire result set back to the the datagrid?

Comment: But, the parameters are passed from the headers of the same gridview

Comment: Get all the data to fill dgvs at once with your query by grouping the records according to your dgvs. And then you put the those records in a loop. If the group changes, that means the current data belongs to next dgv

Comment: @Batu Zet To get all the data with my query, I think I still need to loop my query to pass different parameters at each iteration?

Comment: You can filter your datatable after getting all the data

Comment: Thanks, but how do I pass all the parameters without using nested for loops, because using nested for loops and passing 36*31 combinations of inputs to the queries is the main cause for slowness

Comment: @BatuZet I have used stopwatch in my function and it is not taking much time to populate the data to dgv but it is taking all the time to run the query with 36*31 combinations of trademonths and paymentmonths

Comment: Then maybe your database structure is too much complicated or your `poolpayments` and `poolpaymentadjustments` queries are too much complicated. Can you post your database structure and your queries.